# jetty rewrite handler only with not found URI

Tags: java, url-rewriting, jetty

How to make `org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler` work only with not found URI?

when reqeust URI is not directory or not file.

like Apache Rewrite Module

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty RewriteHandler operates on incoming requests before they are processed by the various handlers / servlet contexts / webapps.

To process "Not Found" would require actual processing first, then a rewrite.

This is out of scope of the rewrite handler.

A better choice would be to setup your webapp, WebAppContext, or ServletContextHandler to have a proper ErrorHandler configuration that routes 404 responses to the desired endpoint within that ServletContextHandler.

Comment: can use result like rewrite URI in ErrorHandler?
if you fine, can you give me a example codes?

Comment: look at the standard Servlet handling of Error Page Mappings and Welcome Files, one (or both) of those techniques could serve you.

Comment: I'm not java user just other side, but i required it.
I hope your answer will helping my java guy.